# Swiper slider - Mousewheel Control allow page scrolling when swiper is on last slide

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have a swiper slider with Module [Mousewheel control](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#mousewheel-control), is there a possibility make it so that at the **end** of the scroll slides (**last slide**) the page continue to scroll.

```js
let swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  speed: 600,
  direction: 'vertical',
  parallax: false,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  mousewheel: {
    sensitivity: 1,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES.

By Mousewheel API module option:

### releaseOnEdges

`false` by deafult.

```
mousewheel: {
  releaseOnEdges: true,
},
```

> Set to **true** and swiper will release mousewheel event and allow page
> scrolling when swiper is on edge positions (in the beginning or in the
> end). [Docs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-mousewheel-releaseOnEdges)

DEMO:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  direction: "vertical",
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  mousewheel: {
    releaseOnEdges: true,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
});

swiper.on('reachEnd', function () {
  console.log('slider reachEnd');
});
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
          />

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
    
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Swiper -->
    <p style="min-height: 100vh">Scroll</p>
    <div class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>

      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <h1>releaseOnEdges API option</h1>
    <br><br>
    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```